# ASP.NET MVC - Call a Action in the controller after a checkBox is checked and return a list of Objects in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How would I do to when clicking the checkBox I call the action "ShowActives" of the controller?

This controller returns a list of elements that are active in the database.

How would I return these elements in the table?

my index is my default controller, clicking the checkBox I would like to call the ShowActives Action

```
 public class CodigosDeOperacaoController : BaseController
 {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_codigosOperacionaisService.GetAll());
    }

    public ActionResult ShowActives ()
    {
        return View(_codigosOperacionaisService.GetActives());
    }
  }
```

My View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CodigosDeOperacao", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    @Html.TextBox("buscar", null, new { @class = "form-control input", @placeholder = "Pesquisar por nome" })
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn" type="submit">
                            <big><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></big>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Mostrar Todos</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right ">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" id="btnNovo" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="min-width: 200px;">Novo código</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    </div>       
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Codigo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </th>

        <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (!item.Ativo == false)
        {
            <tr style="background-color:aliceblue">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "CodigosDeOperacao", new { id=item.Id })" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-bottom: 3px" id="tamanho-botoes">
                        <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                    </a>|
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom: 3px" id="tamanho-botoes" onclick="iniciarExclusao('@item.Id')">
                        <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </table>
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Url.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Something like this should work:

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1"  
  onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("ShowActives", "CodigosDeOperacaoController") %>'" >
```